# Passing ID to Selector - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, selector

I'm having some issues with my code maybe you could help?

**Jquery: *[updated]***

```
<script>
$(function() {

     $(".val_error").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "blind",
    hide: "explode"
 });
 $(".val_open").click(function(event) {
     var target = $(this).attr("id");
     $('#' + target).dialog('open');
    return false;
 });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML: *[updated]***

```
<p class="first_name>
<div class="val_error" id="first_name_err"><?php echo form_error('first_name'); ?></div>
<label for="contact_first_name"><?php echo $label_values->first_name;?></label>
<?php echo form_input('first_name', $form_values->first_name, 'id="first_name"');?>
<button class="val_open" id="first_name">Open</button>
</p>

<p class="last_name">
<div class="val_error" id="last_name_err"><?php echo form_error('last_name'); ?></div>
<label for="contact_last_name"><?php echo $label_values->last_name;?></label>
<?php echo form_input('last_name', $form_values->last_name, 'id="last_name"');?>
<button class="val_open" id="last_name">Open</button>
</p>
```

So basically I'm trying to get the dialog to open for just one ID at a time rather than all at once.. I've tried the following but no luck:

**Jquery I thought would work**

```
<script>
$(function() {

     $(".val_error"+target).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
     });
     $(".val_open").click(function(event) {
            var target = $this.attr("id");
        $(".val_error").dialog("open");
        return false;
     });
    });
</script>
```

Any help / pointers or even ideas would be great!

http://jsfiddle.net/dRRRd/ <- can view here

Comment: Your html is not valid, you can not have two ( or more ) elements with the same id. Try to define and use a data- property (i.e data-target-id )

Comment: @DieVarDump I've sorted that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Element ID's must be unique - you have two `first_name` elements and two `last_name` elements. This will cause issues. (You also have two labels "for" `contact_name` - are there two elements with this ID as well?)
2. In your javascript, `target` is not defined when you call `$(".val_error"+target).dialog({` (it's declared in the scope of another callback function.)

What you want to do is assign a class to the parent element of each form group, then use that as a selector to find your error divs. Try something like this:

```
<p class="first_name">
<div class="val_error" id="first_name_err"><?php echo form_error('first_name'); ?></div>
<label for="contact_name"><?php echo $label_values->first_name;?></label>
<?php echo form_input('first_name', $form_values->first_name, 'id="first_name"');?>
<button class="val_open" id="first_name">Open</button>
</p>

<p class="last_name">
<div class="val_error" id="last_name_err"><?php echo form_error('last_name'); ?></div>
<label for="contact_name"><?php echo $label_values->last_name;?></label>
<?php echo form_input('last_name', $form_values->last_name, 'id="last_name"');?>
<button class="val_open" id="last_name">Open</button>
</p>
```

And then your jQuery selector would be `$(".first_name .val_error")` or `$(".last_name .val_error")`

Comment: How could I go about making the selector dynamic then? I've redone the HTML like you suggested is my JS okay? `  $(".val_error").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   show: "blind",
   hide: "explode"
  });
  $(".val_open").click(function(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#' + target).dialog('open');
   return false;
  });`

Comment: Since the error div's ID is essentially the target's ID + "_err" you **could** just hardcode that in, but it'd probably be better to do something like `$(".val_open").click(function() {$(this).siblings(".val_error").dialog('open'); return false;});` (untested)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things with the following line:

```
var target = $this.attr("id");
```

1. `$this` will look for a variable called `$this`, which does not exist. To get at the contextual jQuery object, use `$(this)`
2. The variable `target` is never read -- maybe you meant `$('#' + target).dialog('open');` on the next line?

But the simplest solution is probably to remove:

```
var target = $this.attr("id");
$(".val_error").dialog("open");
```

..and replace it with:

```
$(this).dialog('open');
```

because only one element gets the `click` event anyway, and that element can be targeted with `$(this)`.